# Dojox mobile simpledialog underlay transparency on Android

Tags: android, dojo, dojox.mobile, simpledialog

I have a problem with dojox mobile SimpleDialog underlay transparency on Android - in the underlay randomly appears black squares (with no transparency), sometimes most of the underlay look in this way. And I don't know if it is a problem with dojox or with android WebView - I use it with PhoneGap and how I can solve it. I create the dialog in declarative way and open as a result of clicking on button.

I work with Dojo 1.9 and Android 4 and I have android:hardwareAccelerated set to true. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which I found is:

In CSS's class: mblSimpleDialogCover I've replaced this:

```
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.5;
```

with this:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

And it's works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you reproduce with your code packaged as web app (without PhoneGap)? Do you reproduce when using one of the test_SimpleDialog*.html in dojox/mobile/tests?

I've tried http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.0/dojo-release-1.9.0/dojox/mobile/tests/test_SimpleDialog.html on HTC One X Android 4.1.1 and I don't reproduce.

Finally, could you tell the exact Android version (4.x.y), the device model, and your PhoneGap version? (if it's not a recent version, did you try upgrading it?)

Comment: It appears on Asus Transformer (exactly device model and Android version unfortunately now I don't remember - it's not mine device). But few minutes ago I found a solution - in CSS's class: mblSimpleDialogCover I changed this: background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.5; with this: background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); and now it's work fine for me. 
Nevertheless, thanks for trying to help.